# Nothing appear when I host flutter web app on Github

Tags: git, flutter, github, github-pages, flutter-web

I want to ask you how I do hosting my flutter web app on Github ,I did all the ways to do that but nothing to show I follow the instructions in this video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8hrJ4oN1u_8&list=WL&index=93&t=1s

and everything went fine to pushing to github as you can see

[image]

It is a simple page a simple static web page, I don't know what is the wrong, here is the picture of my repo on github

[image]

here the link the github provided me
https://sunaarun.github.io/demo-hc/
[image]

I tried to edit the link to go and display index.html

https://sunaarun.github.io/demo-hc/web/index.html#/

but nothing to show
[image]

please can anyone help me with this issue

Comment: In my case, I removed "/" from like this: <base href=""> (inside index.html file) and load page using this url https://sunaarun.github.io/demo-hc/index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a line in index.html in your flutter-web app that needs to know the external path for deployment, and defaults to /.  You need to fix that up before committing it to github.  It is described in index.html as:

```
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    Fore more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base
  -->
  <base href="/">
```

For example, one of my sites has edited that to `<base href="/counter/">` and it works fine.

Comment: should I add  <base href="/">   my github url or what ?  please give more explanation

Comment: It'll be in the $PROJECT/web/index.html file in your project.  You'll have to patch up the base href in the master, or in the build/web/index.html file (which will get wiped out on the next build), or in your deploy process (as you're copying build/web to your git repo for pushing.

Comment: I open index.html file and Commented <base href="/"> .. and now it is working ..thank you so much for the help , I will read about <base> tag .. I am not good at we development .. Thanks alot again